# Dynamically edited form doesn't POST user input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that, when clicked, prompts the user for more info dynamically through an `onclick` JavaScript function:

```
<button type="button" class="gameSubmit" id="create" onclick=
        "addCreateField(event)">create game!</button>
```

Once new info has been loaded into the page, I want the button to submit the form (id `entranceform`):

I trigger the form programmatically on my second button click:

```html
<form id="entranceform" method="POST" >
...
    <button type="button" onclick="addCreateField(event)">create game</button>
</form>
```

```js
function addCreateField({target}){
    var container = document.getElementById("initialinfo");
    var newInfo = document.createElement('div');
    newInfo.setAttribute("id", "createDetails");
    newInfo.innerHTML += "divs and checkboxes and radios"
    container.appendChild(newInfo);

   // here we change the onclick event handler
   target.onclick = () => {
     const form = document.getElementById('myForm')
     form.reportValidity() && form.submit()     
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, the dynamically edited form doesn't POST user input (you can observe this if you submit on the JSFiddle and monitor the network). Why might that be?

JSfiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/qdyajeu8/

Comment: Your form has no method, so why would it use post? Get is the default.

Comment: @j08691 my bad, I didn't paste in the code properly. The fixed version is reflected in the post (and jsfiddle)

Comment: u r just submitting the form data using post method u r not sending post request if u want to send post request u have to write code to post u r data on submit.

Comment: @AmareshSM Could you help me outline how to do that? I thought setting `method='POST'` sends a post request on submit.

Comment: check out this link: https://stackabuse.com/using-fetch-to-send-http-requests-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle actually POST the dynamic form input. You can check using Chrome Dev Tool

[image]